# How to negate @JsonView?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

The following will include only fields that have the `JsonView(View.MyView.class)` annotation:

```
@JsonView(View.MyView.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "offer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> offer(...) {}
```

Question: how can I negate it? Means: include any field **except** the ones having `JsonView(View.MyView.class)`? Especially **without** having to add another annotation on any of the remaining fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. But by adding the following property, any fields not having a `@JsonVniew` annotation will be serialized:

`spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true`

As a result, only a `@RequestMapping @JsonView` will output only non-annotated fields *plus* the ones matching the view.

So if I want to exclude only some fields inside a specific view, I just have to give the to be excluded fields a different view that is not used in the @RequestMapping. Then they are ignored automatically.